# Pandas, ValueError, while checking string endings in column

Tags: python

```
if bool(change_copy.str.endswith('_Ja')):
    print('bereits bearbeitet')
else:
    change_copy.update(change_copy["NAMECHANGE"].where(change_copy["TYP"]!="LM", "LM_"+change_copy["NAMECHANGE"]+"_Ja"))
```

I think its because I'm not iterating over my dataframe.. but dont know how to solve this.. 
Probably someone has an idea?

I just want to make sure, if the string in the columns ends with `"_Ja"`, my Code is not adding a second `'_Ja'`. Same with the `"LM_"` at the beginning of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
df['column_name1'] = df['column_name1'].apply(lambda x: x if x.endswith("_Ja") else "_Ja"+x)

df['column_name2'] = df['column_name2'].apply(lambda x: x if x.startswith("LM_") else x+"LM_")
```